# Multiple developers to do single xcode project without OS X & Xcode Server

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, git

Is it possible to do more then one developers work in single xcode project without having Server OS, Xcode Server Apps?
else 
Tel me the possible ways to do more then one developers work on same project ?

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 1):

In order to make native iOS app you must have xCode IDE which can be installed only on OS X.

If you want to organize a collaboration of a few developers, use GIT repository or analogue.

Comment: Git (github) is the solution for his question indeed. You can run xCode on a vm though .